# Bazel coverage C++ build _coverage_report.data is empty

Tags: gcc, code-coverage, bazel

```
my-project
    ├── driver
    │       ├── BUILD
    │       ├── stm32f446re_gpio_driver.h
    │       ├── stm32f446re_gpio_driver.cpp
    ├── unit_test
    │       ├── BUILD
    │       ├── ut_gpio.cpp
    └── WORKSPACE
```

I have a bazel build structure like above, I am trying to generate test coverage using "bazel coverage" command. The output is PASSED, everything seem fine. But the _coverage_report.dat is empty with 0 size. So then, I cannot generate html file.

```
bazel coverage //unit_test:ut_gpio --combined_report=lcov
```

[image]

I tried to put all srcs file and headers files in the same folder, it worked well. But when I separate to /driver folder and /uni_test folder. It cannot generate valid coverage_report.dat. Do I miss something? Why this happens?

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04, Bazel 3.5.0, gcc 7.5.0

BUILD (unit_test):

[image]

BUILD (driver):

[image]

Comment: Same issue with java too. Please let me know if you any solution

Answer (score -2):

You can set `--instrumentation_filter="//driver[/:]"` in your cmd, for example:

```
bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov --instrumentation_filter="//driver[/:]"  //unit_test:ut_gpio
```